# Requirements for creating a new political party in USA

Tags: united-states, parties, election-requirements

What are the registration requirements for a new federal political party in the USA?

Comment: In what state would this party start? Federal party status is basically just relevant for campaign finance; ballot access is controlled by state laws, not federal.

Comment: Is it some basic common requirements cross-states? I am doing comarative analysis of registration requirements among several counries so I am predominantly interested in some general things. Or could you please provide an example for any particular state?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Federal Registration

The Federal Election Commission handles this at the federal level. According to [their website](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/9871/register-new-political-party-in-usa), registration requirements include:

1. The party should have nominated Presidential and Vice Presidential candidates in numerous states (as well as other candidates for other offices).
2. Engaging in the normal activities of a party, such as voter registration drives.
3. Holding a national convention and having national offices

### State Registration

Federal registration requires already being registered in "numerous states".  Each state can have different requirements. For example, my state (Kansas) requires a [petition](http://kslegislature.org/li/b2015_16/statute/025_000_0000_chapter/025_003_0000_article/025_003_0002a_section/025_003_0002a_k/) to be filed with the Kansas Secretary of State.  The petition must be signed by at least 2% of active voters (operationalized as the number of voters who voted in the last gubernatorial election).

I don't have a general knowledge of state requirements to register a party, but I quickly looked up Nebraska and Maine's requirements and they are similar (although they have different percentages required).